# I can't get new data after apolo fetchMore

Tags: typescript, next.js, apollo, react-apollo

next.js,typescript,react,apollo.
I want to use fetchMore when handleLoadMore is called to get 10 data from the 11th one, but the data in console.log(data) is from 0 to 10, which is the first data I got.
I tried to open the DevTool network, but the network shows data from 11.

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState } from 'react'

import { ChannelLayout } from '@/components/Layouts/ChannelLayout'
import { useFindMyMoviesQuery } from '@/generated/request'
import type { NextPageWithLayout } from '@/types/layout'

const Cannel: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const { data, loading, fetchMore } = useFindMyMoviesQuery({
    variables: { skip: 0, take: 10 },
  })

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  console.log(data)
  if (loading) return <div>loading...</div>

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    const pageSize = 10
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        skip: 11,
        take: 10,
      },
    }).then((result) => {
      setCurrentPage(page)
    })
  }
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button onClick={handleLoadMore}/>
    </Box>
  )
}

Cannel.getLayout = ChannelLayout

export default Cannel
```

As noted above.